# Firebase Data Missing on console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase's real-time database to pull data to my android application. 
The database was working flawlessly until at one pint, I couldn't manually add data in the console. It kept prompting that I had illegal characters (while entering simple strings). So I refreshed the console. Now, many entries are just not there. The funny part is, my Mobile application can pull data from the missing nodes. I don't understand.

PS I've read the other SO post in which refreshing the page fixes the problem. In my case, it's not so.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include steps that will reliably reproduce the issue? Without that or an error message, all we can do is take guesses at the cause.

Comment: are sure you are in the right project ?

Comment: There are no steps. I open the console, the data is missing. I check my phone, the data is there. And yes, Im in the right project